# Offset rows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm calculating the logarithmic slopes between the points (that the user has inserted):

[image]

For that I'm using two DataGrid; first displays the coordinates, and the second displays the slopes. I'm using a pair of DataGrid because I need to update the curve distinguishing what has been changed, the coordinates or the slope.

I would like to display better the values of the slopes: rather that being displayed in the same line as the points, they should be displayed in between the points, as shown in the second figure.

I don't know a way of doing this in WPF, maybe setting a greater value to Height of the header of the second DataGrid, so all rows will be displaced a little (approx 5px), but I can't find a way of doing that.

Could someone guide me to achieve this?

The DataGrid is defined in a pretty standard way:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridSlope" ItemsSource="{Binding Points, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100"
        Background="#19B0C4DE" BorderThickness="1" 
       BorderBrush="#19D3D3D3" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
       CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
       ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" 
       CellEditEnding="s1GridPendiente_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Slope, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}', 
                                           Mode=TwoWay, 
                                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           Header="dB/oct"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: can't you just add some margin on the top to that datagrid?

Comment: The header won't be aligned that way.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you need 2 grids? Is it because you have 2 data sources? Can these be combined into a single data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

To achieve that, you can add this

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 10"></Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

to your `<DataGrid x:Name="gridSlope"  ...` before the `<DataGrid.Columns>`.

You can play with the margin there, or do what you want :) (and remove the bold if you don't like it ... I was just fooling around with it ...)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The last thing to do about this slopes issue is to hide the last value "0.00", but I think I should open a new question for that!

Comment: If you're talking about the slope, then yeah, you'll have n-1 points in that array. You could probably just trim the last point. Anyways, glad I could have helped (and that it was the margin like my comment suggested ;) .

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't perfect but it's close to what you are after.  The problem with this idea is that the DataGridRow clips its content so you can't move the 3rd column as far down as would be ideal.

[image]

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding B}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="C" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=C}" Margin="0,5,0,-2"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


public class DataClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public String C { get; set; }

    public DataClass(int a, int b, String c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}

    public List<DataClass> Data { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Data = new List<DataClass>() { new DataClass(1, 2, "3"), new DataClass(2, 3, "4"), new DataClass(3, 4, "5"), new DataClass(4, 5, "") };
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```